# Unable to draw a Line through SVG Using DOM, Typescript

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I'm trying to add svg to my div element using appendchild function in typescript and the save to add a line inside svg. but i cannot see a line output in my brower. and i even dont see any errors plzz help me out

```js
   this.divElement =  document.getElementById('main');
    // console.log(this.divElement,this.screenHeight,this.screenWidth);

    this.divElement.style.width = '100vw';
    this.divElement.style.height = '100vh';

    this.element = document.createElement("svg");
    this.element.style.position = 'absolute'
    this.element.style.width = '100vw'
    this.element.style.height = '100vh'
    // console.log(this.element.style.width,this.element.style.height,"WH");
    this.divElement.appendChild(this.element)


    this.svgLine = document.createElementNS(this.svgns, 'line');
    console.log(this.svgLine);
    this.svgLine.setAttribute('x1', 10);
    this.svgLine.setAttribute('y1', 10);
    this.svgLine.setAttribute('x2', 130 + 1);
    this.svgLine.setAttribute('y2', 130 + 1);
    this.svgLine.setAttribute('stroke', 'black');
    this.svgLine.setAttribute('stroke-width', '5');
    // this.svgLine.style.position = 'absolute'
    this.element.append(this.svgLine);
```

When i see my console and log the svg, i can see the line element been added but i cannot see the line on the broswer

Answer (score 0):

1. we don't use `getElementById` in Angular, use [reference](https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef) instead.
2. we don't use `createElement` in Angular, use [renderer](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2) instead.
3. Don't put [Thanks in the Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Here is the [Working code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

```
import {
  Component,
  Input,
  ElementRef,
  ViewChild,
  AfterViewInit,
  Renderer2
} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "hello",
  template: `
    <div #main style="100vw">
      <svg #svg1></svg>
    </div>
  `,
  styles: [
    `
      div {
        border: 1px solid black;
      }
      svg {
        height: 500px;
        width: 500px;
        border: 3px solid red;
      }
    `
  ]
})
export class HelloComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild("svg1", { static: false }) svg1: ElementRef;

  constructor(private renderer2: Renderer2) {}


  ngAfterViewInit() {

    const svgLine: SVGLineElement = this.renderer2.createElement(
      "line",
      this.svg1.nativeElement.namespaceURI
    );

    svgLine.setAttributeNS(null, "x1", "0");
    svgLine.setAttributeNS(null, "y1", "0");
    svgLine.setAttributeNS(null, "x2", "200");
    svgLine.setAttributeNS(null, "y2", "200");
    svgLine.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke", "red");
    svgLine.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke-width", "5");
    this.svg1.nativeElement.appendChild(svgLine);
  }
}
```